# RecyclerView in Fragment is sometimes empty on BottomNavigationView item touch

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, bottomnavigationview

My `RecyclerView` in `Fragment` (`FrameLayout`) is sometimes empty on `BottomNavigationView` item touch (sometimes you can touch 5x and it's not empty but then it's empty again until the next touch).

**YouTuberFragment**

```
public class YouTuberFragment extends Fragment {

    private List<YouTuber> youtuber;

    private class GetYouTuber extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getActivity().getAssets().open("youtuber.json");
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) total.append(line);

                String m = total.toString();
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(m);
                JSONArray jsonYouTuberArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("youtuber");

                int youTubersCount = 0;
                if (jsonYouTuberArray != null) youTubersCount = jsonYouTuberArray.length();

                for (int i = 0; i < youTubersCount; i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonYouTuberObject = jsonYouTuberArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    YouTuber youTuber = new YouTuber(
                            jsonYouTuberObject.getString("name"),
                            jsonYouTuberObject.getString("role"),
                            jsonYouTuberObject.getString("picture"),
                            jsonYouTuberObject.getString("episodes"),
                            jsonYouTuberObject.getString("youtube")
                    );

                    youtuber.add(youTuber);
                }
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    public YouTuberFragment() {

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_youtuber, container, false);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        youtuber = new ArrayList<>();
        RVAdapter adapter = new RVAdapter(youtuber, getContext());

        new YouTuberFragment.GetYouTuber().execute();

        RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.rv);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }

}
```

**RVAdapter**

```
class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private Resources res;
    private List<YouTuber> youTuber;
    RVAdapter(List<YouTuber> youTuber, Context context){
        this.youTuber = youTuber;
        this.context = context;
    }

    static class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CardView cv;
        ImageView ytPicture;
        TextView ytName;
        TextView ytRole;
        TextView ytEpisodes;
        Button ytYoutube;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            ytPicture = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yt_picture);
            ytName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yt_name);
            ytRole = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yt_role);
            ytEpisodes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yt_episodes);
            ytYoutube = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.yt_youtube);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public PersonViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_youtuber, viewGroup, false);
        res = v.getResources();
        PersonViewHolder pvh = new PersonViewHolder(v);
        return pvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, final int i) {
        personViewHolder.ytPicture.setImageResource(res.getIdentifier(youTuber.get(i).picture, "drawable", BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID));
        personViewHolder.ytName.setText(youTuber.get(i).name);
        personViewHolder.ytRole.setText(youTuber.get(i).role);
        personViewHolder.ytEpisodes.setText(res.getString(R.string.yt_episodes, youTuber.get(i).episodes));
        personViewHolder.ytYoutube.setText(youTuber.get(i).youtube);

        personViewHolder.ytYoutube.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://" + youTuber.get(i).youtube);

                Intent youtube_url = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                context.startActivity(youtube_url);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return youTuber.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you are running a different thread to gather your data while your adapter initialization is being ran on the main thread and is being rendered before your data can be retrieved. Have you tried rotating the device if it is blank?